# DeliveryDate in Order Item Grid not sorting correctly

Tags: datetime, magento-1.7, gridview-sorting

I have created a sales order item grid in the admin panel in magento. The grid displays the Display Date correctly. However when I try to sort based on the delivery date it does not work. 
I include the delivery date as follows:

```
$this->addColumn('proptions', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Delivery Date'),
        'index'     => 'proptions',
        'renderer'  =>  new Bakery_Core_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Data(),
        'type'      => 'datetime',
    ));
```

In Renderer_Data I do the following:

```
$val = substr($_option['value'],0,10);  //returns format dd/MM/yyyy                    
                $val = str_replace("/","-",$val);  //returns dd-MM-yyyy
                $dateTimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(strtotime($val));
                $format_val = date('d M Y', $dateTimestamp);  // returns e.g. 13 Aug 2013
```

I have set the type in the grid for this column as datetime. However it still doesn't sort the date in the correct order. 
How can I fix this issue?

Thanks,
Neet

Answer (score 0):

I checked the Grid in the Promo and it seems to use 'date' for 'type'

Example

```
    $this->addColumn('to_date', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Date Expire'),
        'align'     => 'left',
        'width'     => '120px',
        'type'      => 'date',
        'default'   => '--',
        'index'     => 'to_date',
    ));
```

Comment: Hi,
Changing the type to date didn't work either. it isn't sorting properly for the Delivery Date.

Comment: Hi, I checked the code , the issue seems to be there because the type is not getting set for this column. Since I am making use of a renderer when adding this column , the type doesn't get set to date or datetime . The minute I remove the renderer the type is set fine in Column.php. I require the renderer, since what we receive from the database is a complete list of Custom Options in an unserialized form. I have created a renderer class Data.php which extends the Datetime.php. Still the issue persists.

Comment: Can you upload the module somewhere I can have a look at?